# Resource, Service, Dao - Namming Conventions

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, rest, naming-conventions

I am developing a RESTful API with Google App Engine (Java), Google Cloud Endpoints, and Objectify. I have organized my project in the following way.

The model classes I just call by name.

```
MyModel.java
```

Then I have three classes for dealing with each model.

1. A class for processing the API call
2. A class for handling the business logic
3. A class for dealing with persistence and database retrieval

*Before anyone asks, even though I am using Objectify, an ORM library, since I am using transactions, there is still enough code so that its worth it's own class.*

The classes are named as follow with the correlating suffixes.

```
MyModelResource.java
MyModelService.java
MyModelDao.java
```

**My Question is, is such suffixing inline with naming conventions for such an architecture?**

I also considered the following since I was using Google Cloud Endpoints.

```
MyModelEndpoint.java
MyModelService.java
MyModelDao.java
```

I know this is not vital to any logic, but naming is important to me. **What are the standards here? What are the conventions?**

Answer (score 1):

The java code [conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) say that the class names should be as concise as possible while not abbreviating, and while being as specific as possible. My takeaway from this is that what you have there is pretty well inline. If you wanted to be more precise you might change service to something more specific, and might write out dao into a non-acronym format.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points:

- While there are naming conventions, I think the ones that you have come up with do specify what the classes stand for to a large extent.
- I would also focus on putting the classes in the appropriately named java package names, so that as your code base becomes larger, there is a logical way to navigate the packages. In other words, your package names should give a good sense to what classes might be in them.
- Augment the above 2 points with appropriate code comments and Unit Tests and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

> “There are 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors.”
>
> ― Leon Bambrick

So when it comes to naming in IT the problem is that people often redefine existing terms such as [service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_(systems_architecture)). So what happend is that something that is rather called [use-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) has for some unclear reason be called "service" even though this did not fit the existing definition of that term. But if some important IT people propose such habbit then the world follows without further thinking and you in the end are forced to do so as well as otherwise you end up fighting windmills. I tried such things for angular naming conventions but [was simply ignored](https://groups.google.com/g/angular/c/rmmj_FruYok/m/tx8rtK3VBwAJ).
I also never understood why a service using the SOAP protocol was implied by the term WebService, etc.
BTW in devonfw we tried to strictly define reasonable [naming, packaging and coding conventions](https://github.com/devonfw/devon4j/blob/master/documentation/coding-conventions.asciidoc) for Java.